# What browser does Outlook web use for addins on mac?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Does anyone know which browser Outlook-web uses for addins on a mac?

background: I am developing an addin for outlook web on a mac and I'm making use of a bootstrap collapsable panel. I also have two icons that I want to have to the left and right of the title, however, the anchor tag used to expand / collapse the panel is forcing a line break. I am wondering if this issue is something in my css or a browser issue since setting display: inline on the anchor tag does nothing.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is strictly on topic.

Comment: It can be for those of us developing Office Add-ins, where the community is minuscule to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins#client-requirements-os-x-desktop) Webkit rendering engine is used, which is nothing but the Safari browser (with limited functionality) is used.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins#client-requirements-browser-support-for-office-online-web-clients-and-sharepoint)

> Any browser that supports ECMAScript 5.1, HTML5, and CSS3, such as
>   Internet Explorer 11 or later, or the latest version of Microsoft
>   Edge, Chrome, Firefox, or Safari (Mac OS).

Comment: Thanks Jodrell but that's not quite what I'm thinking of. This is the requirement to run an addin. I an writing the addin and when it is displayed inside outlook, it is displayed using some browser. I'm looking for what browser that is.

Comment: @cbutler, Ahhh, I suspect its some engine that is more or less compatible with ECMAScript 5.1, HTML5, and CSS3. Depending on the version Outlook, it probably renders your script in annoyingly different ways.

Comment: Yes... I found a work around; to use a ul and add the items as li's and then set display: inline-block; on the li's, and using some bootstrap classes along with some custom css. It would just be good to know what you're dealing with :)